# Is it normal that Entity Model passed to Spring Controller as parameter is detached from jpa context?

Tags: spring, jpa, persistence

I'm implementing simple app using Spring and Jpa/Hibernate (Without data JPA).

I get the parameter from the form which is mapped to Entity model. When I try to save it, it says that it is detached from persistance context - is that normal ? How does it work? Spring when is trying to map request to a model is making a call to database and then it detaches the model from persistance context?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure retrieving and saving the entity are in the same transaction boundary and/or using the same entity manager to get and persist the entity.